# Is it good practice to have lots of if else condition?

Tags: c#, asp.net, if-statement, stringbuilder

In one of my web application  I am using string builder from code behind.

```
StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
if (isLogIN != false)
{
    if (isValidUser == true)
    {
        str.Append("<div id='sfBtnSubmitWrapper' >");
        if (CheckIfAlreadyPlayed())
        {                           
            str.Append("<input type='button'");
            str.Append("value='Predict Now' class='sfBtn' id='sfBtnSubmitAnswer' />");                               
        }
        else
        {
            str.Append("<input type='button'");
            str.Append("value='Already participated.' class='sfBtn' id='sfBtnSubmitAnswer' />");
        }
         str.Append("</div>");
    }
    else
    {
        if (CheckEarnedGame())
        {
            str.Append("<div id='sfBtnSubmitWrapper' ><input type='button'");
            str.Append("value='Predict Now' class='sfBtn' id='sfBtnSubmitAnswer' />");
            str.Append("<p style='color:green'>You have reached your daily limit");
            str.Append("but your earned games still remain.</p>");
            str.Append("</div>");
        }
        else
        {
            str.Append("<div id='sfSettingInfo'>");
            str.Append("<a class='ClosePopupImg' id='closeOptionDiv' title='Close'></a>");
            str.Append("<span id='errorLimitmsg'>");
            str.Append("<p style='color:red'>Sorry !!!</br>You have crossed");
            str.Append("your limit of games.</p></span><span id='btnPlayMore'");
            str.Append("class='sfBtn'>Play More");
            str.Append("</span><div id='optionDiv'></div></div>");
        }
    }
}
```

There is even more (if else) condition that I am using in my real code.I am little bit confuse whether it is good practice to use lots of if else condition or  Is there any other way to do it.

Comment: @Acme Can you suggest me any other way than above  ?

Comment: You have not specified your requirement. You have only asked if a lot of `if-else` is good or bad, and there is no one answer for it. Your code though seems ok to me.

Comment: When the only possible answer is "it depends", the question is not really fit for SO.

Comment: I have to append html markup through string builder and I have to check lots of condition and it looks so messy while using this way.So I am looking for best way to do it.

Comment: @its really diffcult to tell whether you can use switch or nested switch case statments, beacause i am not sure of your requirement.If you think you can implement switch case stmts..it is lot cleaner than using large number of if else ladders/blocks

Comment: @BijayaKhadka You may really really want to save yourself a big headache and consider looking into Razor or ASPX, because if I understand the intent of your code you posted, it's a lot more painful than it needs to be.

Comment: I think using if else condition is best in this condition. Thank YOu

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are talking about is [Cyclomatic complexity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclomatic_complexity), and no it's not that great.

Every time you add a new if statement you essencially create another path that your code can follow and therefore its complexity.

That said, it is not bad to use if/else statements, you can't really code without them.

But as you have already figured out by looking at your code it seems a bit dirty.

So what to do?

Welcome to software design, and design patterns.

Very common design patterns can often over these sorts of [code smells](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell), I would start by going through the [S.O.L.I.D](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_%28object-oriented_design%29) principles to get the basics and then head over to [DoFactory](http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/Patterns.aspx) and read all about some common patterns.

Once you start down this path, you will start seeing simple solutions for [smells like these.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell) for [example](http://www.refactoring.com/catalog/replaceConditionalWithPolymorphism.html).

Answer (score 0):

Should you try to extract every code block  under "if" to functions then should you try to delegate the execution by abstraction (every block/function will be method of class which inherit from common interface)